# Saving all files in for loop not just final file processed by for loop

Tags: python, flask

I am cropping faces from an image and saving them to a directory with a timestamp to create a unique filename.  The issue I am having is the only face that is saved is the final face processed in the for loop.

The 5 faces are found in the image, cropped BUT only the last face cropped is saved.

I'm sure that there is an issue with how I'm handling the for loop and save event, however, I cannot seem to resolve this issue thus far.

```
@app.route("/CropFace", methods=["GET", "POST"])
def crop_face():
    if 'image' not in request.files:
        flash('No file part')
        return redirect(request.url)
    file = request.files['image']
    if file.filename == '':
        flash('No image selected for uploading')
        return redirect(request.url)
    if file and allowed_file(file.filename):
        filename = secure_filename(file.filename)
        file.save(os.path.join(app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER_CROP'], filename))
        # print('upload_image filename: ' + filename)
        flash('Face(s) Successfully Uploaded')
        # Crop faces using face_recognition
        uploaded_file = os.path.join(app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER_CROP'], filename)
        crop_image = face_recognition.load_image_file(str(uploaded_file))
        face_locations = face_recognition.face_locations(crop_image)
        flash("Found {} face(s) in this Event Image".format(len(face_locations)))

# THIS IS THE SECTION I NEED TO RESOLVE THE SAVE ISSUE IN

        for face_location in face_locations:
            # Print the location of each face in this image
            top, right, bottom, left = face_location
            # You can access the actual face itself like this:
            face_image = crop_image[top:bottom, left:right]
            saved_face = Image.fromarray(face_image)
            timestr = time.strftime("%Y%m%d-%H%M%S")
            static_save = saved_face.save("static/nametag/" + timestr + ".jpg")

        flash(" Face Crop Successful, Awaiting NameTag.")
        return render_template('cropface.html', filename=filename)
    else:
        flash('Allowed image types are -> png, jpg, jpeg, gif')
        return redirect(request.url)
    return render_template("cropface.html")
```

[image]

[image]

5 faces found but ONLY 1 Saves.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure this is the correct way to resolve this issue BUT it worked for me.

Simply adding:

```
time.sleep(2)
```

At the end of the for loop, provides a pause for the loop to save each face.

[image]

Comment: Does anyone know of a 'better' resolution? Is it not considered poor programming to use time sleeps?